# Android Application 'Stopping' without LogCat Error

Tags: java, android, sql

I have an Android project (running in emulator) in which clicking the 'Novels' button on the main menu should lead to the values of pieces where the typeField = 0 (ie false) in the 'pieceTable' in the SQL database being displayed in a ListActivity through an ArrayList.

However, when the Novels button is clicked, the application is stopped and a dialogue box shown, stating 'Unfortunately, EnglishLitRevision has stopped'. There is no LogCat output.

I wouldn't be surprised if this is a very basic error out of ignorance, but I would be grateful if anyone can identify the problem.

UPDATE - filter was not set to 'error' on LogCat!

LogCat output is shown below:

```
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lawson.englishlitrevision/com.lawson.englishlitrevision.Novel}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:460)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:265)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.Novel.onCreate(Novel.java:24)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  ... 11 more
```

**I would be grateful if anyone can identify the cause of the error.**

Code from three relevant classes is shown below.

Main Menu:

```
 /**
 * Main Menu (launcher item)
 * @author Daniel Lawson
 * @Version 29/12/13
 */

package com.lawson.englishlitrevision;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    /** Button for accessing novels area */
    private Button novelBut;
    /** Button for accessing plays area */
    private Button playBut;
    /** Button for viewing progress/statistics */
    private Button progressBut;
    /** Button for viewing about screen */
    private Button aboutBut;
    /** Button for exiting the application */
    private Button exitBut;

    /**
     * Method called when activity is started. Sets up required data.
     * 
     * @param savedInstanceState
     *            : The saved state of the application
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sets up layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_layout);
        createButton();
    }

    /** Sets up the buttons */
    public void createButton() {
        novelBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.novelBut);
        playBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBut);
        progressBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNovBut);
        aboutBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutBut);
        exitBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBut);
    }

    /**
     * Method called when novel button is clicked. Starts novel activity.
     * 
     * @param novBut
     *            : The view of the novel button, which has been clicked.
     */
    public void goNovel(View novBut) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Novel.class));
    }

    /**
     * Method called when play button is clicked. Starts play activity.
     * 
     * @param playBut
     *            : The view of the play button, which has been clicked.
     */

    public void goPlay(View playBut) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Play.class));
    }

    /**
     * Method called when progress button is clicked. Starts stats activity.
     * 
     * @param progBut
     *            : The view of the progress button, which has been clicked.
     */
    public void goStats(View progBut) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Stats.class));
    }

    /**
     * Method called when abpit button is clicked. Starts about activity.
     * 
     * @param aboutBut
     *            : The view of the about button, which has been clicked.
     */
    public void goAbout(View aboutBut) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
    }

    /**
     * Method called when exit button is clicked. Quits application.
     * 
     * @param closeBut
     *            : The view of the exit button, which has been clicked.
     */
    public void goClose(View closeBut) {
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Novel:

```
package com.lawson.englishlitrevision;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;

public class Novel extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> novels = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        ManipulateDatabase md = new ManipulateDatabase(this);

        super.onCreate(icicle);
        novels = md.getPieces("0");
        setContentView(R.layout.novel_layout);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, novels));

    }

    public void addNovel() {
        // show text input
        // add the String put in to database as new novel
        // update list
    }

    public void deleteNovel() {
        // show checkboxes
        // allow selection
        // delete selected records from database
        // update list
    }

}
```

ManipulateDatabase:

```
/**
 * Contains SQL statements and manages connections
 * 
 * @author Daniel Lawson
 * @version 29/12/13
 */
package com.lawson.englishlitrevision;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class ManipulateDatabase {

    /** String representing the name of the database */
    private static final String databaseName = "EnglishDatabase.db";

    /** Int representing the current version of the database */
    private static final int databaseVersion = 1;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * String representing the table that stores the name of the piece and
     * whether it is a play or not.
     */
    private static final String pieceTable = "pieceTable";

    /**
     * String representing the table that stores the name of the point made,
     * which piece it belongs to, and which element it pertains to.
     */

    private static final String specificTable = "specificTable";

    /**
     * String representing the table that stores the element, the piece it
     * belongs to, and whether or not it is a character.
     */

    private static final String elementTable = "elementTable";

    /**
     * String representing the table that stores the quote and the point it
     * links to.
     */

    private static final String quoteTable = "quoteTable";

    /**
     * String representing the table that stores the piece and the
     * correct/incorrect responses on various dates
     */

    private static final String statsTable = "statsTable";

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /** String representing the piece field of the piece table */

    private static final String pieceField = "piece";

    /** String representing the type field of the piece table */

    private static final String typeField = "isPlay";

    /** String representing the point field of the specific table */

    private static final String pointField = "point";

    /** String representing the element field of the element table */

    private static final String elementField = "element";

    /** String representing the elType field of the element table */

    private static final String elTypeField = "isCharacter";

    /** String representing the quote field of the quote table */

    private static final String quoteField = "quote";

    /** String representing the ID field of the stats table */

    private static final String idField = "statId";

    /** String representing the correct field of the stats table */

    private static final String correctField = "correct";

    /** String representing the incorrect field of the stats table */

    private static final String incorrectField = "incorrect";

    /** String representing the date field of the stats table */

    private static final String dateField = "date";

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /** String array representing all the fields of the piece table */

    private static final String[] pieceTableFields = { pieceField, typeField };

    /** String array representing all the fields of the specific table */

    private static final String[] specificTableFields = { pointField,
            pieceField, elementField };

    /** String array representing all the fields of the quote table */

    private static final String[] quoteTableFields = { quoteField, pointField };

    /** String array representing all the fields of the element table */

    private static final String[] elementTableFields = { elementField,
            pieceField, elTypeField };

    /** String array representing all the fields of the stats table */

    private static final String[] statsTableFields = { idField, pieceField,
            correctField, incorrectField, dateField };

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /** SQL statement to create the piece table. */

    private static final String createPieceTable = "CREATE TABLE " + pieceTable
            + " (" + pieceField + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " + typeField
            + " INTEGER);";

    /** SQL statement to create the specific table. */

    private static final String createSpecificTable = "CREATE TABLE "
            + specificTable + "(" + pointField + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
            + pieceField + " TEXT NOT NULL," + elementField + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

    /** SQL statement to create the quotes table. */

    private static final String createQuoteTable = "CREATE TABLE " + quoteTable
            + "(" + quoteField + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," + pointField
            + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)";

    /** SQL statement to create the element table. */

    private static final String createElementTable = "CREATE TABLE "
            + elementTable + "(" + elementField + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
            + pieceField + " TEXT NOT NULL," + elTypeField + " INTEGER)";

    /** SQL statement to create the stats table. */

    private static final String createStatsTable = "CREATE TABLE " + statsTable
            + "(" + idField + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + pieceField
            + " TEXT NOT NULL," + correctField + " INTEGER," + incorrectField
            + " INTEGER," + dateField + " DATE)";

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * SQL statement to search the piece table - replace [columnName] and
     * [value] with field to be searched and what value to look for.
     */

    private static final String searchPieceTable = "SELECT * FROM "
            + pieceTable + " WHERE [columnName] = '[value]';";

    /**
     * SQL statement to search the specific table - replace [columnName] and
     * [value] with field to be searched and what value to look for.
     */

    private static final String searchSpecificTable = "SELECT * FROM "
            + specificTable + " WHERE [columnName] = '[value]'";

    /**
     * SQL statement to search the quote table - replace [columnName] and
     * [value] with field to be searched and what value to look for.
     */

    private static final String searchQuoteTable = "SELECT * FROM "
            + quoteTable + " WHERE [columnName] = '[value]'";

    /**
     * SQL statement to search the element table - replace [columnName] and
     * [value] with field to be searched and what value to look for.
     */

    private static final String searchElementTable = "SELECT * FROM "
            + elementTable + " WHERE [columnName] = '[value]'";

    /**
     * SQL statement to search the stats table - replace [columnName] and
     * [value] with field to be searched and what value to look for.
     */

    private static final String searchStatsTable = "SELECT * FROM "
            + statsTable + " WHERE [columnName] = '[value]'";

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * SQL statement to update the piece table - replace [assignValues] and
     * [condition] with items to be altered + their new values and the condition
     * where if true, this change should be applied.
     */

    private static final String updatePieceTable = "UPDATE " + pieceTable
            + " SET [assignValues] WHERE [condition]";

    /**
     * SQL statement to update the specific table - replace [assignValues] and
     * [condition] with items to be altered + their new values and the condition
     * where if true, this change should be applied.
     */

    private static final String updateSpecificTable = "UPDATE " + specificTable
            + " SET [assignValues] WHERE [condition]";

    /**
     * SQL statement to update the quote table - replace [assignValues] and
     * [condition] with items to be altered + their new values and the condition
     * where if true, this change should be applied.
     */

    private static final String updateQuoteTable = "UPDATE " + quoteTable
            + " SET [assignValues] WHERE [condition]";

    /**
     * SQL statement to update the element table - replace [assignValues] and
     * [condition] with items to be altered + their new values and the condition
     * where if true, this change should be applied.
     */

    private static final String updateElementTable = "UPDATE " + elementTable
            + " SET [assignValues] WHERE [condition]";

    /**
     * SQL statement to update the stats table - replace [assignValues] and
     * [condition] with items to be altered + their new values and the condition
     * where if true, this change should be applied.
     */

    private static final String updateStatsTable = "UPDATE " + statsTable
            + " SET [assignValues] WHERE [condition]";

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * SQL statement to delete from the piece table - replace [condition] the
     * condition where if true, this deletion should be applied.
     */

    private static final String deleteFromPieceTable = "DELETE FROM "
            + pieceTable + " WHERE [condition]";

    /**
     * SQL statement to delete from the specific table - replace [condition] the
     * condition where if true, this deletion should be applied.
     */

    private static final String deleteFromSpecificTable = "DELETE FROM "
            + specificTable + " WHERE [condition]";

    /**
     * SQL statement to delete from the quote table - replace [condition] the
     * condition where if true, this deletion should be applied.
     */

    private static final String deleteFromQuoteTable = "DELETE FROM "
            + quoteTable + " WHERE [condition]";

    /**
     * SQL statement to delete from the element table - replace [condition] the
     * condition where if true, this deletion should be applied.
     */

    private static final String deleteFromElementTable = "DELETE FROM "
            + elementTable + " WHERE [condition]";

    /**
     * SQL statement to delete from the stats table - replace [condition] the
     * condition where if true, this deletion should be applied.
     */

    private static final String deleteFromStatsTable = "DELETE FROM "
            + statsTable + " WHERE [condition]";

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * SQL statement to insert into the piece table - replace [values] with the
     * values to be inserted.
     */

    private static final String insertIntoPieceTable = "INSERT INTO "
            + pieceTable + " VALUES ([values])";

    /**
     * SQL statement to insert into the specific table - replace [values] with
     * the values to be inserted.
     */

    private static final String insertIntoSpecificTable = "INSERT INTO "
            + specificTable + " VALUES ([values])";

    /**
     * SQL statement to insert into the quote table - replace [values] with the
     * values to be inserted.
     */

    private static final String insertIntoQuoteTable = "INSERT INTO "
            + quoteTable + " VALUES ([values])";

    /**
     * SQL statement to insert into the element table - replace [values] with
     * the values to be inserted.
     */

    private static final String insertIntoElementTable = "INSERT INTO "
            + elementTable + " VALUES ([values])";

    /**
     * SQL statement to insert into the quote table - replace [values] with the
     * values to be inserted.
     */

    private static final String insertIntoStatsTable = "INSERT INTO "
            + statsTable + " VALUES ([values])";

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * SQLiteDatabase representing the English database
     */

    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;

    /**
     * Instance of DatabaseHelper class utilised to 'access' database
     */

    private DatabaseHelper baseHelper;

    /**
     * Content of the Database Manipulator (ManipulateDatabase class)
     */

    private Activity context;

    /**
     * Boolean to store whether or not this is the first time this base/version
     * has been launched
     */

    private boolean initialLaunch = false;

    /**
     * Scanners to read the .txt lists to to input to database
     */

    private Scanner pieceScan = new Scanner("pieceList.txt");

    private Scanner specificScan = new Scanner("specificList.txt");

    private Scanner elementScan = new Scanner("elementList.txt");

    private Scanner quoteScan = new Scanner("quoteList.txt");

    /**
     * Method to open the database
     */

    private void openSesame() {
        try {
            dataBase = baseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Database couldn't be opened");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to close the database
     */

    private void closeSesame() {
        baseHelper.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPieces(String typePiece) {
        try {
            openSesame();
            ArrayList<String> pieces = new ArrayList<String>();
            String command = searchPieceTable
                    .replace("[columnName]", typeField);
            command = command.replace("[value]", typePiece);

            Cursor cursor = dataBase.rawQuery(command, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                pieces.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(pieceField)));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            closeSesame();
            return pieces;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SQL Problem");
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param contextIn
     *            Context of the MainpulateDatabase class
     */

    public ManipulateDatabase(Activity contextIn) {
        baseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(contextIn);
        context = contextIn;
        openSesame();
        String line;
        String pieceName;
        String isDrama;
        String point;
        String element;
        String quote;
        String isCharacter;
        int commaPoint;
        int commaPoint2;

        if (initialLaunch) {
            while (pieceScan.hasNext()) {
                line = pieceScan.nextLine();
                commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                pieceName = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                isDrama = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, line.length() - 1);
                ContentValues pv = new ContentValues();
                pv.put(pieceField, pieceName);
                pv.put(typeField, isDrama);
                dataBase.insert(pieceTable, null, pv);

                System.out.println("DAMN YOU MORONIC CRETIN!!");
            }
            while (specificScan.hasNext()) {
                line = specificScan.nextLine();
                commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                point = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                commaPoint2 = (line
                        .substring(commaPoint + 1, line.length() - 1)
                        .indexOf(","));
                pieceName = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, commaPoint2);
                element = line.substring(commaPoint2 + 1, line.length() - 1);

                ContentValues sv = new ContentValues();
                sv.put(pointField, point);
                sv.put(pieceField, pieceName);
                sv.put(elementField, element);
                dataBase.insert(specificTable, null, sv);
            }
            while (elementScan.hasNext()) {
                line = elementScan.nextLine();
                commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                element = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                commaPoint2 = (line
                        .substring(commaPoint + 1, line.length() - 1)
                        .indexOf(","));
                pieceName = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, commaPoint2);
                isCharacter = line
                        .substring(commaPoint2 + 1, line.length() - 1);

                ContentValues ev = new ContentValues();
                ev.put(elementField, element);
                ev.put(pieceField, pieceName);
                ev.put(elTypeField, isCharacter);
                dataBase.insert(elementTable, null, ev);

            }
            while (quoteScan.hasNext()) {
                line = quoteScan.nextLine();
                commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                quote = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                point = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, line.length() - 1);

                ContentValues qv = new ContentValues();
                qv.put(quoteField, quote);
                qv.put(pointField, point);
                dataBase.insert(quoteTable, null, qv);
            }

        }

    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Database helper - Three basic methods - required database tasks
     * 
     * @author Daniel Lawson
     * @version 30/12/13
     */

    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private DatabaseHelper(Context theContext) {
            super(theContext, databaseName, null, databaseVersion);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(createPieceTable);
                /*
                 * db.execSQL(createSpecificTable);
                 * db.execSQL(createQuoteTable); db.execSQL(createElementTable);
                 * db.execSQL(createStatsTable);
                 */
                // initialLaunch = true;

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to create table(s)");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + pieceTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + specificTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + quoteTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + elementTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + statsTable);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If it crashed then there is logcat output. Make sure the filter is set to error. Also, make sure that `Novel` `Activity` is declared in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks, I now have LogCat output. I'll edit the original post to see if anyone can identify the issue.

Comment: @otherdan arraylist novels is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the place on which you should look in logcat:

```
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
```

probably this call:

```
novels = md.getPieces("0");
```

returns null value, but from what I see this should happen only when there is an exception inside:

```
public ArrayList<String> getPieces(String typePiece) {
```

so look for problem in this function.

Comment: This does seem to be the problem, I will now try to identify the problem in the method that should return this filled ArrayList. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`novels` ArrayList is null

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java/

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 18:26:06.344: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
```

ArrayAdapter.java:330

```
328
329    public int getCount() {
330        return mObjects.size();
331    }
```

`ArrayAdapter` uses getCount which returns the size of the list indicating `novels` is null which means you should look at

```
 novels = md.getPieces("0");
```

Comment: This does seem to be the problem, I will now try to identify the problem in the method that should return this filled ArrayList. Thanks!

Comment: @otherdana also check `md` is properly initialized and is not null

Comment: I have changed the code in the body of the catch so that an ArrayList is returned even when an Exception occurs, and the Novels list works in this instance, hence the method must be the problem.